# Assign a dynamic IP into domain in NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs server and I get server ip address with the following code.

```
    //To fetch IPv4 address of server
  var getIpAddress = function()
  {
      var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
        var ips = 0;

        for(var dev in ifaces)
        {
            ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details){
                //console.log(details);
               if(details.family == 'IPv4' && details.internal == false)
               {
                   //ips[dev+(alias?':'+alias:'')] = details.address;
                   ips = details.address;
               }
            });
        }
      return ips;
  };
```

And I have a client code as below:

```
function loadDatabaseData()
{
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", "http://192.168.80.143:2800/load", true);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status == 200) {
            links = JSON.parse(oReq.response).links;
            nodes = JSON.parse(oReq.response).nodes;
            update();
        }
    }
    oReq.send();
}
```

When I took the IP value in Nodejs Server, I want to assign this into a domain. So I can use this domain like 'http://foo.bar.hello/load' instead of 'http://192.168.80.143:2800/load' in aforementioned code. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://192.168.80.143.xip.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that your IP address begins with 192.168 I am assuming the server and client are communicating through a Local Area Network (not going through the internet).

The Domain server on your network is what will allow you to assign a textual name to the IP address of your server. Typically the computer name of your server is registered as a domain, and the address 'http://192.168.80.143:2800/load' should already by mapped to 'http://:2800/load'. Depending on the OS of the server there are many ways of finding out the computer name. On Windows machines, you can see it when you right click on My Computer and select Properties (windows xp-7) or in System -> About (windows 8 - 10).

You probably can setup a domain server to run on your server. Your router may have an implementation of a domain server as well.

P.s. this is more of the networks administration question than a Node.js programming question.